# illegalstateexception in displaying list view

Tags: android, listview, illegalstateexception

i am getting an error for displaying my content in listview.
the error says:

```
 05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity                    ComponentInfo{com.android.lthomepage/com.android.lthomepage.ListViewDetails}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    column '_id' does not exist
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at com.android.lthomepage.ListViewDetails.displaylistView(ListViewDetails.java:77)
05-03 08:00:13.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3341):     at       com.android.lthomepage.ListViewDetails.onCreate(ListViewDetails.java:42)
```

the listview code is as follows:

```
    Cursor cursor=way.fetchDetails();
    String[] columns=new String[] {WayDataBase.KEY_NAME,WayDataBase.KEY_APPNO,WayDataBase.KEY_AMOUNT};

    int[] to=new int[] {R.id.name,
            R.id.continent,
            R.id.region};

    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listview=getListView();
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the database code is:

```
public Cursor fetchDetails()
{

    createAllValuesTable();
    Cursor mCursor=db.query(AllValuesTable, new String[] {KEY_NAME,KEY_APPNO,KEY_AMOUNT}, null, null, null, null, null);

     if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
          return mCursor;
}
```

what is the problem i cant seem to figure out??
i dnt dont have any column as _id and i dnt noe from wer is it showing this!
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From Android Developer Site**

**Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) will not work.**

You are trying to use a cursor with `SimpleCursorAdapter` which REQUIRES a column called `_id`. Its as simple as editing your table creation statement and adding a column called `_id`. The declaration should be as follow

`_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`